# Use script inside jsrender

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, jsrender

I need to use something like,

```
@{
   var Name = string.Empty;
}
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="menu">
@Name = $('#NameContainer').attr("data-name");
<div class="menu-item">
    @if (Name == "A")
    {
        <div class="option">A</div>
    }
    else if(Name == "B") {
        <div class="option">B</div>
    }
```

But I am getting `Name` value as `empty`. How to assign value to global variable inside jsrender ?

Answer (score 3):

The docs on running code in JsRender templates are here: http://www.jsviews.com/#allowcodetag

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript global variable instead of Razor template's global variable, To use javascript code in jsrender template, you have to allow code tag using settings.

```
$.views.settings.allowCode(true);
```

And now you can write script in `{{* ... }}` tag.
In your example:

```
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="menu">
{{* window.Name=$('#NameContainer').attr("data-name");}}
<div class="menu-item">
{{* if(Name == "A") { }}
    <div class="option">A</div>
{{* } else if(Name == "B"){ }}
    <div class="option">B</div>
{{* } }}
```